# ffmpeg can't find codec to cut 10 seconds movie

Tags: ffmpeg

I tried to cut 10 seconds from movie and convert to MP4. But sometimes I have a error like below:

```
Duration: 00:08:52.40, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1126 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: wmav2 (a[1][0][0] / 0x0161), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 96 kb/s
    Stream #0:1: Video: wmv3 (Main) (WMV3 / 0x33564D57), yuv420p, 640x480, 1000 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
[mp4 @ 0x5614bbea1300] Could not find tag for codec wmv3 in stream #0, codec not currently supported in container
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argumentStream mapping:
```

What does this error mean? Should I install some extra codec?

My exec line looks like:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wmv -ss 00:00:00 -to 0 -c copy 0:00:10 output.mp4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Could not find tag for codec wmv3 in stream #0, codec not currently supported in container`

You're trmiing the file without recompressing, and ffmpeg does not write Windows Media 9 streams into MP4, so either recompress:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wmv -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:10 output.mp4
```

or output to a different container, like Matroska:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wmv -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:10 -c copy output.mkv
```